# IIS7: HTTP->HTTPS Cleanly

Tags: xml, https, iis-7

Is there a clean way to redirect all attempts to going to an HTTP:// version of a site to its HTTPS:// equivalent?

Comment: Answer can be found on James Kovac's blog: http://jameskovacs.com/2007/05/09/how-to-autoredirect-to-a-sslsecured-site-in-iis/

Comment: If you are on IIS 7 and on R2 [here](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/) is a guide which works and the most "clean"

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is as described [here on IIS-aid.com](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/redirect_http_to_https_iis_7). It's web.config only and so if you change server you don't have to remember all the steps you went through with the 403.4 custom error page or other special permissions, it just works.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and for bonus points it's completely self-contained so you don't have to create a new website as outlined in the accepted answer

Comment: Will this fire for all URLs regardless of filetype. e.g. A direct URL to a txt file?

Comment: This worked for me with the exception that I had to modify the redirect URL to https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: This also worked for me. I had to add the application I was running under... http://localhost/app1/ => http://{HTTP_HOST}/app1/{R:1}

Comment: For anybody that doesn't already have a rewrite section, place the rules in the following sections of the web.config: <system.webServer><rewrite><rules> ... </rules></rewrite></system.webServer>

Comment: make sure Microsoft URL Rewrite Module is installed  on the IIS server

Comment: For SEO reasons you should use redirectType="Permanent". Review https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033085?hl=en&ref_topic=6033084

Comment: This does not work for me on IIS 8, it causes `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in Chrome.

Comment: The Rewrite Rule above solved my problem but it was not until I first went into SSL Settings in IIS for this domain and unchecked Require SSL (even though only Ignore was checked).

Comment: FYI this should go in a `Web.config` file in the root of your website

Comment: Need IIS bindings on both 443 and 80

Answer (score 14):

The most easy and clean solution I found was to

1. In SSL Settings -> require SSL
2. In Error Pages -> On 403.4 error -> Redirect to the HTTPS site
3. In Error Pages -> Edit Features Settings... -> Set Detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote request

The benefit is that it requires no extra lines of code.
Downside is that it redirects you to an absolute url.

Comment: works perfectly (on IIS 8.5 / 2012 R2). and no tinkering with the web.config

Comment: Could you please give an example of this downside? In what circumstances would it happen and why is it a negative thing? If you could add it to your answer, that would be great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio Im unsure since it was so long ago. but I believe when i meant that it redirects you to an absolute url i meant a "base url". For example "http"://mywebsite.com/hellokitty would be redirected to "https"://mywebsite.com
thus losing some path information, this would break every existing link with extra path information.

Answer (score 5):

A clean way changes only the URL scheme from http -> https and leaves everything else equivalent. It should be server-side so that there are no browser issues.

JPPinto.com has [Step-By-Step instructions](http://www.jppinto.com/index.php/2009/04/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-iis-7/) on how this is done, except that they use javascript (HttpRedirect.htm) instead of a server-side redirect. For some reason, I couldn't get IE run the javascript if you have ‘Show friendly HTTP error messages’ enabled, which is on by default. Another thing with the script is that redirection to path didn't work even in FF or Chrome. The script always redirects to root. (Maybe I have missed something, because it should redirect to path.)

For these reasons I have used an ASP page for the redirect. The downside is of course that this requires classic ASP to be enabled on the server.

OpsanBlog has an [ASP script and instructions](http://blog.opsan.com/archive/2005/04/17/395.aspx) that work well with IIS6.

I've had a few issues using this method with IIS7. User interface issues mostly, since IIS7 makes it really easy to miss something.

- First, you need to install ASP as a
  web server role feature.
- Second, using a virtual directory didn't not
  work as expected in IIS7 and I didn't
  try to debug this. Instead, I put the file in the root folder of the site and used
  the url '/SSLRedirect.asp' in the
  403.4 error page to reference it.
- Last, the most tricky part, you **must NOT enforce SSL for SSLRedirect.asp**. Otherwise you'll get an 403.4 error. To do this you pick the file in IIS7 'Content View', and switch to 'Features View' so that you can edit the SSL settings for the single file and disable 'Require SSL' checkbox.

IIS manager should show the file name in the header.

Comment: The linked instructions at JPPinto.com have been updated to highlight that this does not work on IIS 7.5 or R2. They say you will get a lock violation due to changes in security in the newer versions of IIS. They suggest using the URL Rewrite 2.0 method instead (similar approach as per the answer from @toxaq).

Answer (score 0):

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
if (!Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("localhost") && !Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
}
```

Comment: I can easily get around this redirect by putting "localhost" somewhere into the URI, e.g. the query string http://yourdomain.com?localhost=true

I would suggest checking the Request.Url.Host property instead

Answer (score 0):

I use classic asp (intranet) and on pages that requires login the logon include file does the redirect:

```
if Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT_SECURE") <> "1" or Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") <> "on" then 
    Response.Redirect "https://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL")
end if
```

This of course does not include GET or POST data. So in effect it's a clean redirect to your secured page.

Answer (score -4):

I think by 'cleanly' you mean like with a 300 redirect.  Config for a lot of servers & languages [here](http://www.somacon.com/p145.php).