# Remove "www" from URL in global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the following to force https on my site:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
    + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can add to this code that will also strip "www" from the url as well? That way if a user types "http://www.URL.net" it will automatically go to "https://URL.net".

**note: I'm using IIS6 and can't upgrade to IIS7.

Comment: Have you considered maybe trying to do this using your webserver?

Comment: why not doing this by modifying the web.config?

Comment: Other than replacing ``Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]`` with ``Regex.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"], @"^www\.", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)``?

Comment: take a peak at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347/iis7-http-https-cleanly  and follow that to http://jameskovacs.com/2007/05/09/how-to-autoredirect-to-a-sslsecured-site-in-iis/  you'll need to tweak the approach.

Comment: I'm using IIS6.

acfrancis - I tried that, didn't do anything. Still lets me use "www" in the url

Comment: acfrancis - nevermind I think I had a typo. Your suggestion did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User "acfrancis" solved the problem:

replace `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]` with `Regex.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"], @"^www\.", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

So the full code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://" + Regex.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"], @"^www\.", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

Works perfectly. Forces HTTPS and removes WWW from the url.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this with [IIS' URL Rewriter extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

In addition to rewriting URLs, it can also perform redirections, including a built-in template for canonical hostnames. That way the redirection is applied to every request, not just those that go through ASP.NET.