# how to redirect from http to https if we explicitly give http in the url

Tags: http, iis, https

I want to redirect an url from http to https if we explicitely give http in the url bar.

```
// I tried  keeping the below code snippet in web.config



<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="some url" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This is working fine when I tried like this in the url bar, for 
    example: sampledomain.com,
    but this is not working when:

1. I explicitly give http://sampledomain.com in the url bar
2. I try to access directly  home page of our site i.e sampledomain.com/Home

I want the solution for the above two methods.

Comment: Incase your IIS version is 7 , we  already have an existing post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347/iis7-http-https-cleanly. Please mention iis version also in the question

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps:

[HTTP to HTTPS redirects on IIS 7.x and higher](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx)