# IIS redirect to HTTPS changes the URL

Tags: redirect, iis

Ii'm trying to force HTTPS redirection in IIS, based on the article

https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule

what's strange, when I create the Redirect URL as follows

```
https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}
```

and I open http://some.com/somePage, instead of being redirected to https://some.com/somePage I'm redirected to https://some.com/h

what's that `'h'` letter at the end and why `'somePage'` is missing ?

Comment: Checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347/iis7-http-https-cleanly ?

Comment: Also if you use any nlb s, you can configure that there too. (it's more clean way imo)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that redirects every `http` link to it's `https` version.
If you put it in the web config it should work:

```
<rule name="Redirect to www MAIN"  stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourdomain.com$" />
  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect"  url="https://www.yourdomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```